# How to add multiple conditions in one equality condition?

Tags: java

I would like to know how to add multiple conditions in one equality condition. For example, how to specify multiple equalities for x here.`(x == (1 || 2 || 3))`. This is how I've tried but doesn't work.

Comment: Use `if(x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3)`. Also this is a question you can simply google and not fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can either do `if(x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3)` or use `switch`:

```
switch(x) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        // do something
        break;

    default: // it's not 1, 2 nor 3
        // do other things
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Set.of(1, 2, 3).contains(x)) { // Java 9

if (Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).contains(x)) { // <= Java 8
```

This seems an adequate pattern for `x is in the set {1, 2, 3}`.

Comment: Hu? What does this answer have to do with the question? Am I not getting something? Why is this upvoted? I don't see how this answers the question without any explanation given.

Comment: @Ben `x == (1 || 2 || 3)` is somewhat intended as `x in {1, 2, 3}` (_is element of_). In java I have sufficiently often seen the ugly Arrays.asList being used for that.

Comment: Well why certainly that is resemblant I don't think just pasting this here without any explanation is a good answer, even less so with numbers not even matching the question's numbers.

Comment: @Ben I see. Thanks will add text.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways with if in direction you want:

```
1. if(x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3) { ... }

2. if(x.equals(1) || x.equals(2) || x.equals(3)) { ... } // better
```

You can read more about `Java` [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm) for example.